# Wordpress Form Validation using jquery.validate.min.js not working

Tags: wordpress, jquery-validate, validation

I have a custom built form in Wordpress (I considered using a form plugin but it is a 3 step form and none of the plugins I saw seemed suitable).  I am trying to implement a form validation plugin following the steps here: http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/validate-forms-in-wordpress-with-jquery/

Here's what I've got in my wordpress template:

```
<form name="lpsOrderForm" id="lpsOrderForm" method="post" class="contact-form" action="/payment-information/">
<input name=action type=hidden value=lps_calc>
<input name=page type=hidden value=2>
<input name=size type=hidden value=2>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Paper</label></li>
<li><select name=paper id=paper onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=4 >70# Gloss</option>
<option value=5 >7 Pt Reply/Uncoated</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Ink</label></li>
<li><select name=ink id=ink onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=6 >Full Color Both Sides</option>
<option value=7 >Full Color One Side</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Bleed</label></li>
<li><select name=bleed id=bleed onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=8 >Yes Bleed</option>
<option value=9 >No Bleed</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Fold</label></li>
<li><select name=fold id=fold onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=0>None</option>
<option value=10 >Half-Fold</option>
<option value=11 >Quarter-Fold</option>
<option value=12 >Tri-Fold</option>
<option value=13 >Double Parallel-Fold</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Bindery</label></li>
<li><select name=bindery id=bindery onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=0>None</option>
<option value=14 >One Perf</option>
<option value=15 >Two Perfs</option>
<option value=16 >Three Perfs</option>
<option value=17 >Four Perfs</option>
<option value=18 >Five Perfs</option>
<option value=19 >L Perf</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<ul class=form-list>
<li><label>Quantity</label></li>
<li><select name=quantity id=quantity onchange="lps_calcprice()">
<option value=0>0</option>
<option value=20 >1000</option>
<option value=21 >2000</option>
<option value=22 >3000</option>
<option value=23 >4000</option>
<option value=24 >5000</option>
<option value=25 >10000</option>
<option value=31 >15000</option>
<option value=26 >25000</option>
<option value=27 >50000</option>
<option value=28 >75000</option>
<option value=29 >100000</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li><label>Company/Name:</label></li>
        <li><input class="fws4" type="text" name="lps_deliveryname" id="lps_deliveryname"/></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li><label>Address Line 1:</label></li>
        <li><input class="fws4" type="text" name="lps_deliveryadd1" id="lps_deliveryadd1"/></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <li><label>Address Line 2:</label></li>
        <li><input class="fws4" type="text" name="lps_deliveryadd2" id="lps_deliveryadd2"/></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li><label for="city">City:</label></li>
        <li><input class="small-tbox" type="text" name="lps_deliverycity" name="lps_deliverycity" id="lps_deliverycity"/></li>
       <li><label for="states">State:</label></li>
       <li><label for="zip">Zip:</label></li>
       <li><input class="small-tbox" type="text" name="lps_deliveryzip" id="lps_deliveryzip"/></li>
    </ul>
    <input class="checkout-button-blue" type="submit" /></fieldset>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

You'll notice a call for onchange in the selects.  The function calculates a price and displays via AJAX and is working properly.  It is enqueued and localized in my plugin with proper add_action calls.  Here is the javascript file for the lps_calcprice function:

```
function lps_calcprice(){
jQuery.post(myAjax.ajaxurl, jQuery("#lpsOrderForm").serialize()
,
function(response_from_the_action_function){
    jQuery("#lps_price").html(response_from_the_action_function);
}
);
```

}

And here is the plugin file, which I call trace_validate_form:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Trace Validate Form
 * Description: Validate form data instantly with jQuery. Uses <a     href="http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/">jQuery Form Validation</a> plugin by Jörn Zaefferer.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Pro Blog Design
 * Author URI: http://www.problogdesign.com/
 * Lic
*/

/**
 * Add jQuery Validation script on posts.
 */
function trace_vc_scripts() {
//  if(is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( "jquery-validate",     WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/trace_validate_form/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'jquery-validate',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css',
        array(),
        '1.0'
    );
//  }
}
add_action('init', 'trace_vc_scripts');

/**
 * Initiate the script.
 * Calls the validation options on the comment form.
 */
function trace_vc_init() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#lpsOrderForm').validate({
            rules: {

                lps_deliveryName: {
                    required: true,
                },

                lps_deliveryAdd1: {
                    required: true
                },

                lps_deliveryCity: {
                    required: true
                },

                lps_deliveryZip: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    digits: true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                lps_deliveryName: "Please enter a name for the sample/delivery address.",
                lps_deliveryAdd1: "Please enter a street address for the sample/delivery address.",
                lps_deliveryCity: "Please enter a city for the sample/delivery address.",
                lps_deliveryZip: "Please enter a 5 digit zip code for the sample/delivery address."
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'trace_vc_init', 999);
?>
```

When I don't put anything in the fields and click Submit, it just moves on to the next page.  I am fairly new to Wordpress so its very possible this is a simple fix.  I suspect it has something to do with the form action, but I'm not sure what to change it to to get the form validation to work.  When I view the source, I see the JS files in the head and I don't get any errors in Firebug.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

*Note: I removed the state input intentionally as it was loading from inside a php evaluator plugin in Wordpress and I didn't want to make it any more confusing.

Comment: When you check firebug for errors are you checking it after you have clicked submit?

Comment: Do you have any other JavaScript code you have not shown us?  Any other `click` or `submit` event handlers?  These can over-ride the plugin's own submit event handler.

Comment: Jrod - I am checking Firebug both before and after the submit.  Sparky - I do have onchange events tied to some select boxes.  I have edited the post and added the additional code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went on to other things I needed to finish for this project and just got back to validating the form.  Turns out I needed to add "class=required" to the inputs.  Works like a charm now!  Silly...